# php - exec() run in background

Tags: php, shell, command-line, exec

I am trying to execute few `.js` binaries using PHP `shell_exec()`

> THE GOAL : I want to execute couple of scripts all at once to save
>   time. I am `NOT` worried about response and result I get. I just want
>   to run them all at once or atleast without waiting for any exec() to
>   complete it action.

I have already tried adding `> /dev/null &` which I think equivalent to `> NUL` in windows.

As I am on windows environment Is used `> NUL` as in result it, just suppressed the output of script. But still took same time and stopped the execution further till it completed.

```
shell_exec('phantom.exe test.js > NUL &');
```

This is the code I am using.
What I am doing wrong here?

Also I am not sure what is the windows equivalent of `"> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"`

Comment: Yes similar but solution not working for me. the command `"> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"` is for linux there . as i am on windows environment  Its creating problems

Comment: then read the answers for windows